# FrameLayout setVisibility() does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I'm using FrameLayout like a stack of views to change using the onClick event, but it's not working.

The FrameLayout frameEvento shows fine but when I click it calls my method but
dont change the frames visibility.

<---- Fragment code ------->

```
<code>
View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_layout, container, false);

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) V.findViewById(R.id.homeLinearLayout);

FrameLayout f = (FrameLayout) V.findViewById(R.id.frameEvento);
f.setVisibility(View.GONE);
f.requestLayout();

FrameLayout f1 = (FrameLayout) V.findViewById(R.id.frameEventoSecundario);
f1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
f1.requestLayout();

ll.invalidate();
```

<---- Layout code ------->

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/homeLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/frameEvento"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeBotaoEventoPricipal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bt_hsm"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:onClick="goEventoPrincipal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/expomanagement"
        android:text="" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeBotaoEventoSecundario"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/bt_bdw"
        android:onClick="goEventoSecundario"
        android:contentDescription="@string/brasil_design_week"
        android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
 android:id="@+id/frameEventoSecundario"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
    android:visibility="gone"
 >

     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_header_bdw"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:contentDescription="@string/brasil_design_week"
        android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="UHUHUH"
    android:textSize="6pt"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="PLOKO"
    android:textSize="5pt"
    />

            <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="FDSAF"
    android:textSize="5pt"
     />

            <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="QWERT"
    android:textSize="5pt"
     />

                            <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="ABCD"
    android:textSize="5pt"
     />
    </LinearLayout>
 </FrameLayout>  
</LinearLayout></code>
```

Comment: It looks like is not updating the view.. even removeAllViews does not work

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you were calling `findViewbyId()` on ll rather than V

```
FrameLayout f = (FrameLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.frameEvento);
```

You don't need to call request layout since invalidate will redraw your view.
By the way , to what "container" refers to?

Comment: I'm gonna try your suggestion, the container is a ViewGroup: ViewGroup container;

Comment: I removed the request calls and now getting the frame from linearlayout but it's still not hidding the FrameLayout "frameEvento"

Comment: Where and how do you get the container?

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  if (container == null)
  {
   return null;
  }
  
  this.inflater = inflater;
  this.container = container;
  
  return (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_layout,
    container, false);
 }

Comment: Are you sure container is not null?